# Android - TextView on an ImageView, with bounding size equal to the Imageview Size

Tags: android, textview, imageview, scale

this one's be puzzling me for a bit... hopefully there's an easy solution.

I want to create a textView with a background (think in the context of a form of some sort).  The problem is, I want the maximum size of the textview to be bound to the size of the background image.  I've tried a couple of ways:

- Using the background property of TextView directly, but this scales the image when the text gets big

- Using an ImageView and TextView overlayed, but I couldnt work out how to get the textView width to bind to the width of the ImageView

- Hardcoding the maxWidth property of the textView to some dp value.  This works - although, I seem to come across variants of this problem all the time and haven't figured a way to do it dynamically.

Any ideas??

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create a custom view that derives from TextView, and then override the setBackground method and where you can force the size of your text view to the size of background.

One more word, you might also use `android:ellipsize` to `marquee` to avoid overflowing of text, this is a common technique used in the API.